Почему такой ответ? Вопрос 9 глава 7 Объектно-ориентированное программирование в C++ 4-е изд. Р.Лафоре
Вопроc 9 главы 7: Напишите выражение для доступа к 4-му элементу 2-го подмассива двумерного массива twoD.
Ответ который я дал:  twoD [1][3] // индексация элементов начинается с 0 \_()_/
Ответ в приложении Ж: twoD [2][4]  // Почему так?
Я не прав или в книге ошибка?
Прикладываю рисунок из книги где элементы индексируется как я ответил.


А что будете делать, если нужно описать доступ к нулевому элементу?

twoD [1] [0] // он же первый

Т.е. вас не смущает, что вы то так, то так интерпретируете номер элемента? Как бы то ни было - тема скользкая, и сомнения всегда будут.

Как отмечается в ответе: в книге перевод подвел.

Ну вы все равно будете встречаться и с фразами типа "начиная с первого элемента", где имеется в виду a[0], и "начиная с нулевого элемента", где имеется в виду то же самое. Дело не только в переводе, но и в сложившейся практике двоемыcлия ;-)

Я думаю я усвоил что: a[0] // 1-ый или нулевой, a[3] // 4-ый или третий. С другой стороны если искать плюсы то хорошо что есть только две точки зрения, а не больше, иначе это был бы хаос.

There are two hard things in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors  ;)

В таких случаях лучше всего обращаться к оригиналу. В оригинальном издании вопрос звучит так:

Write an expression that accesses element 4 in subarray 2 in a two-dimensional array called twoD

Лично я перевел бы это как "напишите выражение, которое обращается к элементу 4 в подмассиве 2", но не как "к четвертому элементу второго подмассива" — а это, согласитесь, немного разные вещи... Тут скорее вопрос не на нумерацию с 0, а на порядок индексов.
Он пишет

Notice that the first array element is numbered 0.

но не Notice that the array element 1 is numbered 0.
Думаю, что в данном случае вас несколько подвел перевод...
